# Get from process ID a object back

Tags: java, windows, jna

I am developing a Java application. In there I want to start a process. This is done by the *JNA 4.0* Framework (capsel Kernel32.dll).

Now I want to obtain a object through the process id of the application.

### Here's my code:

```
package de.test.windows;

import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;

public class TestWindows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WinBase.STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new WinBase.STARTUPINFO();
        startupInfo.dwFlags = 1;
        WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference processInformation = new WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference();

        boolean status = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(null, "C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram\\Program.exe", null, null, true, new WinDef.DWORD(0), Pointer.NULL, System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), startupInfo, processInformation);

        if (status) {
            System.out.println("Process-ID: " + processInformation.dwProcessId);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how can I get from Process-Id a object back?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using Runtime.getRuntime().exec method?

Comment: Yes, I want to start the exe in the Background (starting as a process). And this process I want to directed.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to get? You can get [a handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to the process using the PID but this isn't going to give you access to the process' memory.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: I want to get a casted object, so I can do things with this object

Comment: @HarryJohnston, i want to get back a object, which i can cast to an "QlikView" object

Comment: That means the question is specific to the QlikView product and should have been tagged accordingly.  I recommend that you delete this question and ask a new one, tagged qlikview, and making it clear what sort of object you are trying to create.  Include the fully qualified name of the object class you are trying to get.